# select text and replace in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, for-loop

I am having trouble solving this. I need to create a grid with square emojis. 11 squares across and 68 rows. I have created that. now my problem is targeting a square in a specific row and position in the row, and replacing it with a different emoji. the class .emoji-generator is a textarea element. i tried appending it and that seems to do the trick. but i need to replace the square with a different emoji and not add it to the line. there could only be 11 characters in each row. what is the best way of going about this?

```
var SQUARE_EMOJI = '\u25FB\uFE0F ';
var DROPLET_EMOJI = '\ud83d\udca7';

function reset() {
    for (var i = 1; i<=68; i++) {
        for(var y = 0; y <11; y++) {
            $('.emoji-generator').append(SQUARE_EMOJI);
            if (i == 6 && y == 5 ) {
                $('.emoji-generator')[y].append(DROPLET_EMOJI);
            }
        }
        $('.emoji-generator').append('\r\n');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`textarea` element content is not manipulated by the `append` method, which is destined for inserting nodes. Instead you should use the `val` method for setting its content. And to improve performance it is best to do that only once at the end of your function:

```
var SQUARE_EMOJI = '\u25FB\uFE0F ';
var DROPLET_EMOJI = '\ud83d\udca7';

function reset() {
    var content = '';
    for (var i = 1; i<=68; i++) {
        for(var y = 0; y <11; y++) {
            if (i == 6 && y == 5 ) {
                content += DROPLET_EMOJI;
            } else {
                content += SQUARE_EMOJI;
            }
        }
        content += '\n';
    }
    $('.emoji-generator').val(content);
};
```